# Vega-lite: Pie Chart with multi-selection in the legend

Tags: json, charts, visualization, pie-chart, vega-lite

I'm trying to make a pie chart in vega-lite and be able to select the categories to include.

Here is my first attempt ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhIhkiyvggMgjr8EHAWUDpyVnDqhlAB5GzqAJ6UiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgaZgZ2WgAjEolZXBoACwAvgo16WSZWWgATC2l5WgAbD19dQMNqADMY21NAAwzILX1Q6gdKxNLm9vzu2IH7agA7Mf9g1MXaAAcXQC6PSAxcQl6szsA+l84PE0KBMFkcJcQOFIjQ8gAzGyCZQQKpbO4NV5KJg0UJoEAWMhwPFdD6YdQhCDwzIIKqgRGRZKgz6xYE-fEnQaA1kg0lY6H2ADWzPBkPx9igIA+xKgbGUuLIIvggWZSDIZHUfDq+IgDFpSkRsWU+NaEyUoqhAEcGCEdIEdKQpUpZYJMszDciORihuaIVDZGwELjSlLSUA))

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data and multi-selection per category.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "selection": {
    "category_select": {
      "type": "multi",
      "fields": ["category"],
      "bind": "legend"
    }
  },
  "transform": [{"filter": {"selection": "category_select"}}],
  "mark": {"type": "arc"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image: full pie]

However, when I select a `category`, **it is not possible to select more than one**:

[image: only category 4]

How to support multi category selection, say `1` and `6`, in a way that the pie proportion is recalculated?

[image: categories 1 and 6 are selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data and multi-selection per category.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]},
          "bind": "legend"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "arc"},
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "category",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"symbolOpacity": 1}
        },
        "opacity": {"value": 0}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"selection": "test"}},
        {"calculate": "datum.value", "as": "value2"}
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "arc"},
      "encoding": {
        "theta": {
          "aggregate": "sum",
          "field": "value2",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal", "legend": null},
        "opacity": {"condition": {"param": "test", "value": 1}, "value": 0.5}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"theta": "independent", "opacity": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: Exactly this! You rock. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This allows multi select when holding down the shift key.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data and multi-selection per category.",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"category": 1, "value": 4},
      {"category": 2, "value": 6},
      {"category": 3, "value": 10},
      {"category": 4, "value": 3},
      {"category": 5, "value": 7},
      {"category": 6, "value": 8}
    ]
  },
  "params": [{
    "name": "test",
    "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["category"]},
    "bind": "legend"
  }],

  "mark": {"type": "arc"},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"aggregate": "sum", "field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "category", "type": "nominal"},
     "opacity": {
      "condition": {"param": "test", "value": 1},
      "value": 0.2
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! it does allow multiple selection, but it does not recalculate the pie. Selecting 6 and 1 should produce a pie with 1/3 in 1, 2/3 in 6. I will extend the original question to clarify that.

Comment: You can leave your upvote on here BTW ;)